# How to not trigger Aniamted.View onTouchStart on clicking touchableopacity in child component

Tags: react-native

I currently have a code architecture as follows:

```
<Animated.View onTouchStart={()=> console.log("ontouchstart")}>
  <View></View>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> console.log("hi pressed}> //should only trigger this when this is pressed.
    <Text>hi</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</Animated.View>
```

where the touchableopacity is the child component of the animated view. I was wondering if it is possible if i press the touchableopacity, it will only trigger the touchable opacity instead of both touchableopacity and the aniamted view.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Pass the prop disabled

```
<Animated.View onTouchStart = {() => console.log("ontouchstart")}>
<View></View>
 <TouchableOpacity disabled={true}  onPress = {() => console.log("hi pressed}> //should only trigger this when this is pressed.
  <Text>hi</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
</Animated.View>
```